# How to expand all the subsections on the sidebar toctree in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar, sections, toctree

I was wondering if there is a way to expand all the subsections under the headers that are included in the `index.rst` file?

As an example, here is how it is:

```
Section 1
Section 2
Section 3
```

And here is how I would like it to be:

```
Section 1
  Subsection 1.1
  Subsection 1.2
  Subsection 1.3
Section 2
  Subsection 2.1
  Subsection 2.2
  Subsection 2.3
Section 3
  Subsection 3.1
  Subsection 3.2
  Subsection 3.3
```

If I click on Section 1, it shows what's under that, but if I click on Section 2, contents of section 1 are hidden and only 2 is shown. I would like all 2 sections to be expanded every time I'm on the index page. I've tried adding `toctree` and `maxdepth`, nothing works.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `index.rst` file to the question?

Comment: If you are using the ReadTheDocs theme, you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669376/show-entire-toctree-in-read-the-docs-sidebar

Answer (score 13):

Well, i lost approximately 3.4M neurons trying to read sphinx source code (was it written by a bunch of rabbid reckless raccoons ?! so many levels of abstraction).

So :

- make your own sphinx theme (use a 3rd party theme as a base, very easy. I use 'readable' theme for that)
- in the directory where you have theme.conf, add a "fulltoc.html" template, containing one line:

fulltoc.html:

```
{{ toctree(collapse=False) }}
```

(Heh, notice the 'collapse' argument?)

- in sphinx conf.py, modify the html_sidebars option to add your template; and declare your theme

conf.py:

```
html_theme_path = [customized_readable_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
html_theme = 'customized_readable'
html_sidebars = {'**': ['fulltoc.html', 'relations.html', 'sourcelink.html', 'searchbox.html']}
```

- rebuild documentation

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sphinx_rtd_theme, you can change the maximum depth of the sidebar menu in the html page by changing the 'toctree maxdepth' value defined in the file *layout.html*. This file is usually located in the directory `source/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme`. There are several solutions:

- The simplest, fastest solution: [Show deeper toctree in sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669376/show-entire-toctree-in-read-the-docs-sidebar)
- You are using an old version of the theme. Then you can set a new 'maxdepth' value (e.g., 3) in the line that says:

  ```
  {% set toctree = toctree(maxdepth=3, collapse=False, includehidden=True) %}
  ```
- You are using a newest version of the theme. Then you may have these lines in the file *layout.html*:

  ```
  {% set global_toc = toctree(maxdepth=theme_navigation_depth|int,
                              collapse=theme_collapse_navigation|tobool,
                              includehidden=theme_includehidden|tobool,
                              titles_only=theme_titles_only|tobool) %}
  ```

  In this case, you may define 'theme_navigation_depth' in theme.conf:

  ```
  [options]
  theme_navigation_depth = 3
  ```

Recompile after the change is done... and don't forget to enjoy the Sun!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's an open bug about this:
https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/455

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done for the mobile-ready "sphinx_rtd_theme" theme.

Add to your [custom JavaScript](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) the following [Vanilla] JS:

```
function toctreeExpand ()
{var toctree=document.querySelector('button.toctree-expand');

 toctree.focus ();
 toctree.click ();
} // function toctreeExpand ()                                                                

function deferToctreeExpand ()
{// flush any pending housekeeping events first...                                            
 setTimeout (toctreeExpand);
} // function deferToctreeExpand ()                                                           

function init ()
{var anchors=document.querySelectorAll('a.reference.internal');

 toctreeExpand ();
 for (var anchor of anchors)
     anchor.addEventListener ('click', deferToctreeExpand);
} // function init ()                                                                         

window.addEventListener ('load', init);
```

It expands only the top-level entries -but that's a hell of a lot better than the default of showing the tree completely collapsed as a single entry! This could be improved upon by (re-)expanding a nested branch where you just clicked (possibly three levels down...) But I have a full inbox; so the fix above was acceptable for now for me...